# pushbot notifications are not receivable on registered device

Tags: android, pushbots

I am trying to send notifications to user using pushbot. my device is registered successfully with the alias name. I have created a web service which is running well and sending the notifications to the dashboard(history and insights) but I am unable to receive notifications on registered device through the API

I have used these 3 lines to do so

```
Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(LoginActivity.this);
Pushbots.sharedInstance().registerForRemoteNotifications();
Pushbots.sharedInstance().setAlias("admin");
```

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="project.hermle.linuxbean.swexpress_dm">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<permission android:name="project.hermle.linuxbean.swexpress_dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="project.hermle.linuxbean.swexpress_dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="false"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".HelpingClasses.MyApplication">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.sampleapp.MESSAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.OrderStatusActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.TimerActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.AdminHomeActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.RestoHome" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.TimeSelectorActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.AddRestaurantActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.CreateNewOrder" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.TimerActivityResto"/>
   <!-- <receiver
        android:name="com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="project.hermle.linuxbean.swexpress_dm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>-->

    <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.DefaultPushHandler" />
    <service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
</application>
```

here I am unable to resolve

```
 android:name="com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
```

I don't Understand what is the problem. your help is appreciated..thank you